# Missing UFW file - WARNING "Couldn't stat '/etc/ufw/before.rules'"

Tags: command-line, server, ufw

I am trying to configure UFW on Ubuntu 20.04lts and this file is missing from my system and I get this warning "Couldn't stat '/etc/ufw/before.rules'".

Is there any way to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: see also: [I need to regenerate ufw files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322161/i-need-to-regenerate-the-ufw-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to obtain a copy of the default before.rules file from the /usr/share/ufw directory:

```
$ sudo diff -s /usr/share/ufw/before.rules /etc/ufw/before.rules
[sudo] password for steeldriver:
Files /usr/share/ufw/before.rules and /etc/ufw/before.rules are identical
```

So,

```
sudo cp /usr/share/ufw/before.rules /etc/ufw/
```

In fact, it appears to be a symlink to the corresponding iptables rule file,

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/ufw/before.rules
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Apr  2  2020 /usr/share/ufw/before.rules -> iptables/before.rules
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple fix once I figured it out.

Use Sudo -i to change to root user

Use nano after the # and create the missing files

Now have /etc/ufw/ the before.rules, after.rules, before6.rules and after6.rules

Now I can setup my UFW